# Puppet : Is this the correct way to generate external facts?

Tags: puppet

I am slightly confused about external facts.
In the simplest form, I could create a json file in the facts.d folder and get it to work.
But I need it built dynamically, via some shell script which creates the json file. I have created the following and gotten it to work but I cannot tell whether this is the right way to do it:

1. shell script in the facts.d folder

   ```
   cat <<END>some_facts.yaml
   ---
   myfacts_array:
   END
   for file in `some folder`  
   do
     echo "  - $file" >>some_facts.yaml
   done
   ```
2. The yaml file in turn looks like this

   ```
   ---
   myfacts_array:
     - 123456
     - 456789
   ```

Is this the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet relies on Facter for collecting facts, including external ones.  Facter has supported structured, executable, external facts only since version 3.5, which is a little less than two years old.  If your version of Facter is older, and you cannot upgrade, then you'll need to find a workaround, such as periodically writing a flat YAML or JSON file in the external facts directory.

If you do have a suitable version of Facter, then the script to execute must

- reside in the external facts directory
- start with an appropriate shebang line
- be executable
- produce well-formed YAML or JSON output representing a hash whose keys are the fact names, and whose values are the associated fact values.<sup>*</sup>

If the script source you presented is meant to be a complete example then it is at least missing a shebang line, but the output appears to be correctly formed.  Beyond that, I haven't any comment about whether what you present is "the right way" to do it.

---

<sup>*</sup> YAML or JSON is required to produce *structured* facts this way.  For plain string facts you can instead output  `KEY` = `VALUE` pairs, one per line.

Comment: It works just fine John. The redundancy ( ie having both a shell script and  json file in the facts.d folder ) is what is throwing me off. I will proceed with this solution. Accepting your answer and +1

Comment: @souser, I guess I don't understand what redundancy you are talking about.  I certainly did not mean to imply any.  You do not (should not) need to have both a script and a flat file for the same external fact(s).  If the same fact is expressed in both forms, then it is not documented which one is used.

Comment: let me try removing the yaml file creation then.

Comment: Yup, that appears to have worked ! It picked it up almost immediately. I did not even need to perform a puppet run.